# Ever since Firefox got updated to version 30 I get annoying permission messages to open pdfs

Tags: windows-7, firefox, pdf

Every time I try to open a pdf with Firefox, I get

[image]

After I click on it the following opens up

[image]

I press "Allow and remember", but it does not remember.

How can I ensure that it remembers?

Comment: It remembers for that page. BTW, it's an important security feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tool->Addons->Plugins->Adobe Acrobat->Always activate