# Firefox prompts to activate Adobe Acrobat despite "Always activate" enabled

Tags: windows, firefox, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I'm using Firefox v33.1.1 on Windows and I can't get Acrobat reader to activate automatically. For instance, I was trying to view [this PDF document](http://www.ams.org/notices/201003/rtx100300357p.pdf) and I received the "*Activate Adobe Acrobat*" screen.

[image: activate screenshot]

This is despite having Adobe Acrobat set to "*Always Activate*" in `about:addons`, as suggested in [a related question](https://superuser.com/questions/773626/ever-since-firefox-got-updated-to-version-30-i-get-annoying-permission-messages). I also have `plugins.click_to_play` set to `false` in `about:config`.

Note sure if this is related, but my application lists looks odd. I used to have Foxit Reader installed and Firefox seems to remember this, despite the application being long since uninstalled. But presumably this only relates to the selection of the right plugin to use?

[image: applications page]

Comment: Does the "activate Acrobat" alert come from Firefox, or does it come from Acrobat? maybe show a picture of the dialog.

Comment: @MaxWyss It is Firefox that presents the alert. I've added a screenshot.

Comment: Just to make sure that everything is configured properly, you might have a look at http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-browser-acrobat-xi.html and then follow the link to the Firefox help in the Firefox section. I have a suspicion that the Acrobat plug-in has not yet been properly activated (which is different from setting it to take action in that table).

Answer (score 0):

"about:config

extensions.blocklist.enabled --> false

This worked for me (I was mostly annoyed by Adobe acrobat plugin check)

-- Gabor " https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.support.firefox/UsZU_ia-pI4